# oracle to snowflake query conversion

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I m trying to convert oracle to snowflake

```
HASH(NAME CONCAT '#' 
    CONCAT Address CONCAT '#' 
    CONCAT DECODE(phone,'true','Y','N') CONCAT '#' 
    CONCAT column_name, 123456) hash_key
```

Can anyone please help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT HASH(NAME || '#' 
  || ADDRESS || '#' 
  || DECODE(PHONE,'true','Y','N') 
  || '#' || COLUMN_NAME
) AS HASH_KEY
```

Check the documentation for specifics on hash functions and variations on the concatenation function.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/hash.html

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/concat.html